# Выполнение функции по таймеру

Tags: c#, функции, таймер

Как можно сделать выполнение функции по таймеру? При этом нужно передавать в функцию несколько аргументов.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Snake
{
    class Snake
    {
        int X;
        int Y;
        int Direction;
        List<Body> body;

        public void SetStartPos(int Y,int X)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
        public void SetDirection(int Direction)
        {
            this.Direction = Direction;
        }

        public int GetPosX()
        {
            return this.X;
        }
        public int GetPosY()
        {
            return this.Y;
        }

        public List<Body> GetBody()
        {
            return this.body;
        }

        public void Move()
        {
            switch(Direction)
            {
                case 2:
                    this.X += 1; //->
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.Y -= 1; // Up
                    break;
                case -1:
                    this.Y += 1; // Down
                    break;
                case -2:
                    this.X -= 1; //<-
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    class Body
    {
        int X;
        int Y;
        public void SetPos(int Y, int X)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
        public int GetPosX()
        {
            return this.X;
        }
        public int GetPosY()
        {
            return this.Y;
        }

    }
    class Fruit
    {
        int X;
        int Y;
        public void SetPos(int Y, int X)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
        public int GetPosX()
        {
            return this.X;
        }
        public int GetPosY()
        {
            return this.Y;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static Timer aTimer;
        public static void update(Snake snake,List<Fruit> fruits,char[,] field, ConsoleKeyInfo key)
        {

            if (key.KeyChar == 'd')
            {
                snake.SetDirection(2);
            }
            if (key.KeyChar == 'w')
            {
                snake.SetDirection(1);
            }
            if (key.KeyChar == 's')
            {
                snake.SetDirection(-1);
            }
            if (key.KeyChar == 'a')
            {
                snake.SetDirection(-2);
            }

            Console.Clear();

            field[snake.GetPosY(), snake.GetPosX()] = ' ';
            snake.Move();
            field[snake.GetPosY(), snake.GetPosX()] = 'O';
            field[fruits[0].GetPosY(), fruits[0].GetPosX()] = '?';
            List<Body> body = snake.GetBody();

            for (int i =0;i<27;i++)
            {
                string test="";
                for(int l=0;l<38;l++)
                {
                    test += field[i, l];
                }
                Console.WriteLine(test);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



        char[,] field = { 
                {'/','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','|'},
                {'|','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','/'},};


            List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
            Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
            Snake s = new Snake();

            fruit.SetPos(12,10);
            s.SetStartPos(10, 10);

            fruits.Add(fruit);

            ConsoleKeyInfo key;
          //  do
          //  {
          //      key = Console.ReadKey();
          //      update(s, fruits, field, key);
          //      //Console.WriteLine(key.Key + " клавиша была нажата");
          //      
          //  }
          //  while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape); // по нажатию на Escape завершаем цикл





            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Interval = 2000;

            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

            // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;

            // Start the timer
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program at any time... ");
            Console.ReadLine();

            void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                update(s, fruits, field, key);  // ТУТ ПРОБЛЕМА!<-------------
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: @tym32167 в конец пролистай и там комментарий!

Comment: Все равно не понятно в чем проблема

Comment: Пролистал вашу портянку кода, стало ещё хуже. Как весь этот код относится к вашей проблеме? В чем суть вашей проблемы? Как вы сами пытались решить вашу проблему и что не получилось?

Comment: @tym32167 может и портянка я же только учусь. Суть в том что нужно выполнять функцию с параметрами раз в n времени

Comment: Под портянкой я имел ввиду много кода, который не относится к вопросу. Чтобы передать состояние или событие таймера, вы можете либо использовать лямбда выражения с захватом переменных, либо сохранять свои переменные в состояние класса, либо использовать таймер, который может принять состояние как параметр.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что `key` не определен изначально.

Замени кусок кода в методе `Main` на следующий:

```
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 500;

        aTimer.Elapsed += (ss, e) =>
        {
            update(s, fruits, field, key);
        };
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;



        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program at any time... ");

        while(true)
        {
            // передаем FALSE что бы не отображать клавиши в консоли
            key = Console.ReadKey(false);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) break;
            update(s, fruits, field, key);
        }

        aTimer.Enabled = false;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("bay!");

        Console.ReadLine();
```